# Get SelectSingleNode index with XPATH

Tags: xpath

I want to get the index of a node using XPath, but I'd love to do it in a single line. I want the int that I'm storing to double as proof of existence of the node, and the position of the FIRST occurrence of a matching node.

What I have now does what I want, but it matches the LAST occurrence of a matching node instead of the first. Can I alter this to get me the first one?

```
int base_Schemes = xmlWebConfig.SelectNodes("/configuration/Security/Authentication/schemes/scheme[@type='ssoscheme, sso']/preceding-sibling::scheme").Count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the `position()` function?

Try `/configuration / Security / Authentication / schemes [@type = 'ssoscheme, sso'] / preceding-sibling::scheme / position()`.

Comment: I'm new to Xpath, so this will probably work, but it's not letting me store it as an int because SelectNodes returns an XmlNodeList. Can I get around this?

Comment: I changed it to int basePosition = xmlWebConfig.SelectNodes("/configuration/Security/Authentication/schemes/scheme[@type='SSO.SSOScheme, SSO']/preceding-sibling::scheme/position()").Count; but when I run it, it keeps complaining. Is this only supported on Xpath 2.0+? Adding .Count was the only way to get it to accept the line.